# Large number of points in PCA plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a 4309082 x 14 matrix in R, of which I have successfully (and quickly!) performed a principal components analysis of using the `prcomp` function.

However, when wanting to visualize these results using `biplot`, R will just hang for minutes until I have to abort the calculation. I imagine this is because of the large number of points (> 4 million). Any suggestions on how to perform this visualization in a quick/efficient manner?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe uniformly sample and have a quick look how it looks like?

Comment: You could try to bin them. for example using the `geom_hex` from `ggplot2` https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_hex.html